# How to remove "JS chart by amCharts" text from amChart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

How can I remove the branding text from an amChart chart?

> JS chart by amCharts

Is there a way to remove that text in the chart configuration?

Image of such a chart:

[image]

Answer (score 38):

amCharts employee here. The branding text/logo is on the free version of the library. As stated on the license terms:

> **Free license**
>
> Use anywhere you want **as long as you don't mind a small amCharts attribution on charts**

If you want to remove the text, you have to [purchase a license](http://www.amcharts.com/online-store/). See the [license FAQ](https://www.amcharts.com/online-store/licenses-explained/) for information on what license is appropriate for your use case. You can reach out to AmCharts support for further clarification on the license terms.

If you already have a license and are using amCharts v3, just download the files from [the support site](https://www.amcharts.com/support/use-support-area/), upload them to your web server and use those instead of the files on the amCharts CDN. If you're using npm or just wish to use the CDN files with your license, contact amCharts for instructions on how to apply your license. Do note that support for amCharts v3 will end at the end of 2020, so you may want to consider migrating to v4 for any further support and fixes.

If you have a license and you are using amCharts v4, the instructions are available in your support account. You will need to create a support account if you don't already have one and attach your license (order ID and email used to purchase the license) to your account to view the instructions.

Finally, if you're still having trouble with applying your license, contact amCharts and provide your order details.

We don't provide instructions on how to hide credits on a public forum for obvious reasons.

Comment: well to be exact, the licensing does not seem restrict to remove the logo. 
It requires to have a small amCharts attribution on the chart, no ?
A user might want to put that attribution on top, or right side.

Comment: It does restrict removing the logo as it *is* the attribution; in versions prior to v4 it was a text link in the chart area. Further down in the [license FAQ table](https://www.amcharts.com/online-store/licenses-explained/), there is an entry for "Removable amCharts branding," which is set to "No" under the Free license column. Note that you can position the logo/branding through different properties depending on the library version if you don't have a paid license.

Comment: See that's why I am concerned with such "canceling" answers..
The license of Version 4 says the following:
"You do not disable, hide or alter the branding link which is displayed on all the content generated by amCharts software unless you provide some other adequately prominent attribution to amCharts."

This means you are ALLOWED to remove the attribution completely if you have a compareable similar attribution.
So I would consider the question as valid and unanswered.

Comment: Who determines what is a comparable attribution? This is a grey area where we'd prefer you reaching out to us for a acceptable replacement rather than hacking a workaround that we clearly frown upon, as you've noticed from the previously deleted answers.

Comment: you created that gray area yourself. It's your own license wording !
But given that wording a simple link to your site should satisfy the license.
I've not looked at previously deleted answers but I'll oppose a removal of a valid answer just as I oppose downvoting correct answers. 
Stackoverflow is not about playing "nanny" but about helping developers solve their tasks.

Answer (score 11):

**amCharts Version 4 license:**
(https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/blob/master/dist/script/LICENSE)

**The relevant part about logo/attribution:**

> You do not disable, hide or alter the branding link which is displayed on all the content generated by amCharts software unless you provide some other adequately prominent attribution to amCharts.

**In the second paragraph it repeats this by saying what you can not do:**

> Use amCharts software without any kind of prominent attribution
> (bundled or custom)

You have the permission to remove the logo/attribution but to do that without breaking the free license you need to place something comparable.
With a bit common sense applied everyone knows what to do and what not.
I would assume that a link below your chart "Powered by amCharts" to the amcharts.com website would be sufficient to satisfy the license. Or the logo with a link.

**Solutions:**
One thing you can always do is remove it by a CSS query by jquery:

```
$('g:has(> g[stroke="#3cabff"])').hide();
```

But using their official method is recommended:

**When using Version 3**

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "hideCredits":true,
```

**When using Version 4:**

```
am4core.addLicense("ch-custom-attribution");
```

Just make sure you include a proper replacement.
License requirement:  `...unless you provide some other adequately prominent attribution to amCharts.`

Also if you use another version of amCharts than '4' you need to read the license conditions.
I only made sure the current 4 version allows it, though it's probably the same  with V3 given the official support in the API.

Keep in mind that it is quite simple for a company to search for websites who use their chart without the attribution.
Adding a small logo/link is a common thing.
Take a look at "Tradingview" charts, even Multi Billion USD companies (Binance for example) have no problem giving them attribution for their chart.

I found this question because I am combining two charts, overlaying each other forming one chart. So the attribution needs to be changed.
Given the "takedown" answers on stackoverflow on all these questions I had to do it myself

Comment: John, your response basically contains information on how to illegally circumvent amCharts license, which might confuse users that would start using software in breach of license. Logo is the prerequisite of free usage of otherwise fully functional software. The only legal way to remove is to acquire a commercial license, at which point user receives full information on logo removal. I therefore suggest you remove the portions of your response with logo removal code. I hope you find it reasonable.

Comment: @martynasma That's incorrect. The license is a one page document and on both sections mentioning the 'attribution' the license allows removing it when adding a custom attribution.
It's legal and obviously allowed by the license terms so I would appreciate if you remove your comment.
If you don't like your own license I recommend to fork the project and make a new license.
Today is 13/04/2021, the license for copies of amCharts until today is as I described.

Comment: I'm going to go on a limb and assume you're not a IP lawyer (correct me if I'm wrong). However, what you are doing here is giving other users a legal advice, which in turn may harm them when they inadvertently breach the license. I understand you might feel like you're fighting a big evil corporation, but instead you're just screwing over a tiny 5-person company, who invested hundreds of hours into development of software, and just want their fricking logo shown in return.

Comment: I've quite some experience with IP, have written my own licenses and even hold patents and a couple brands. But I am not an IP lawyer.

Would you be so kind and let me know what the following part of the license means (to you)?
"... unless you provide some other adequately prominent attribution to amCharts."

Comment: I don't think this discussion is going anywhere. You're right in that license is vague about the form of the attribution. We're developers - not a corporation. And we wanted to keep the license as simple as our own lawyers would allow. I guess you can keep your response. I just wanted to make it clear for anyone reading this that this is your own interpretation of the legal text, and that they should take it with a grain of salt, and perhaps contact amCharts to make sure. Cheers.

Comment: @martynasma I actually don't think the license is vague about this at all, it is quite precise that you need to keep the original attribution or put another one there.
It's similar to other charts I've seen, they also want to be mentioned when used for free.

I asked you because I would really like to hear your interpretation of the license, how you could interpret it to say this is not legal is something I'd put a bounty on:)

Comment: This answer is full of misleading information. One should check the official website before anything else. https://www.amcharts.com/online-store/licenses-explained/

Comment: @KushalJ. Be welcome to point out anything I wrote that is "misleading".
Instead of posting a link no one needs because I actually linked and quoted the license itself.

Comment: @John that's true as well!

Answer (score 7):

For amCharts5 just call `dispose()` on `_logo`, which is an attribute of `Root` class. For example:

```
const root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");
root._logo.dispose();
```

Of course, you probably shouldn't do so, if license does not allow it and you don't plan to acquire the license. Otherwise, it is convenient to hide this for the time being as it sometimes overlaps with other elements and accidental click on the logo opens up a new browser tab, which is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether i am allowed to answer this question but due to lack of information and stack overflow being a free resource for everyone

Here is what can be used to remove that

```
[title="JavaScript charts"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

I highly encourage everyone to buy the license tho

Answer (score -1):

**For amCharts Version 4:**

```
chart.logo.disabled = true;
```

**For amCharts Version 5:**

```
let chart = am5.Root.new('chartdiv');
chart._logo.dispose();
```

Comment: This is against amCharts license.